# Layout differences from one Iphone 6 to another

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I know it must be something simple, but I still don't get what is happening. Last week I got a new `Iphone 6` device because the old one broke, and all the sudden, my app layout is a mess when running on Xcode. Now, I redid all the `constraints` and it is now working fine. But when I tried to build and run the app om my wife's   `Iphone 6`, it looked just like my old one. Anyways, now, from one device to another, there are some important layout differences. What is going on?

Now, when taking pictures of the screen one device has `1136x640` and the other has `1334x750`. I know my issue has to do with this, just don't know how to deal with the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have one of the devices set to scaled display. (It's a setting in settings somewhere.)

### EDIT:

The setting is in Settings, Display and Brightness, Display Zoom.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. But which `auto layout` `constraint` am I missing? Because some of my views are messed up.

Comment: It's not that your missing some magic constraint. It's probably that you have some hard-coded sizes or positions that don't adapt correctly to the different screen sizes. You should test and debug your layouts on both zoomed and non-zoomed screens.

Comment: ok, thanks. I just thought there was something special to avoid all the testing.